# Eclipse Java EE + Bitnami Tomcat Stack

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, bitnami

This is my situation:

- Eclipse ide that i use to develop java web apps.
- Tomcat from apache.
- Tomcat stack from bitnami.
- OS Windows 8

If i deploy and debug to the apache tomcat all work without problem.

If i try the same thing with the bitnami stack, i see the exact same output from the console, like it is starting well, but actually it doesn't and it gets to the timeout saying it was unable to start withing 45 seconds.
I tried to increase the timeout but that's not the problem.

In both cases the Server Location is set to Use Tomcat installation, and i added my project to the source, everything else in the server config is default.

I'm not an expert of tomcat and java webapp deploying, and i need to get it working with the bitnami stack.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it, seems more a problem from eclipse.

In the server configuration i noticed the HTTP port was not listed and it was commented in server.xml

Could this be because the bitnami stack uses port 80 instead of 8080?

Anyway setting the port 80 in server.xml solved the problem.